# No me funciona eventListener de una variable JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero hacer que, cuando el usuario de clic en un botón, se ejecute una función, que lo haga cambiar de color, pero al hacer el eventListener , me dice que `"btn.addEventListener" is not a function`. Alguien sabe porqué?
Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
btn=document.getElementsByClassName('btnCambiarColor');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
btn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.btnCambiarColor {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 7px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.btnCambiarColor.active {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnCambiarColor">Cambiar color</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), así como [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) y [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), devuelven una lista de elementos y no un elemento puntual. Por lo tanto no poseen el método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Sus elementos sí poseen dicho método. Solo tienes que hacer es acceder a los que te interesen y hacer lo que quieras con cada uno, uno por uno.

Estas *listas* no son precisamente **Arrays** o objetos de la misma clase. En cualquier caso puedes crear uno a partir de ellas mediante [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

---

Supongamos que quieres agregar un listener a todos los botones, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
const botones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
botones.forEach(boton =>
   boton.addEventListener('click', () =>
      console.log(boton.textContent)
   )
)
```

```html
<button>Botón 1</button>
<button>Botón 2</button>
<button>Botón 3</button>
```

Recuerda que siempre es buena idea tener la documentación a mano.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que, a la variable btn, si obtienes el elemento con `className` (`getElementsByClassName()`) , no funciona, al igual que con `querySelectorAll`. Tienes que obtenerlo por `id`. El código quedaria así:

```js
btn=document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
btn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.btnCambiarColor {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 7px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.btnCambiarColor.active {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnCambiarColor" id="btn">Cambiar Color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

*El error* `btn.addEventListener no es una función` *aparece porque la variable* `btn` *es un array de elementos y el método* `addEventListener` *se utiliza en un elemento* **DOM** *y no en un* **array** *de elementos*.

Cuando utilizas `btn=document.getElementsByClassName('btnCambiarColor')` obtendrás un `HTMLCollection` **[**button.btnCambiarColor**]**

Este es un objeto que representa una colección de elementos que se utiliza para almacenar un grupo de elementos que comparten el mismo padre.

`button.btnCambiarColor` es el objeto HTMLCollection que contiene un único elemento de botón con la clase *btnCambiarColor*, y el índice **0** en el objeto se refiere al primer elemento de la colección, que es el propio botón.

Cuando declaras

```
btn=document.getElementsByClassName('btnCambiarColor');
```

obtienes una colección de todos los elementos de la página que tienen la clase `btnCambiarColor`.

Para corregirlo, indica el índice **0**:

```
btn=document.getElementsByClassName('btnCambiarColor')[0];
```

```js
btn=document.getElementsByClassName('btnCambiarColor')[0];


btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
btn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.btnCambiarColor {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .btnCambiarColor.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <button class="btnCambiarColor">Cambiar color</button>
```

getElementsByClassName : **[...Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**
HTMLCollection : **[...dom_obj_htmlcollection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_htmlcollection.asp)**